# What prevents Particle Swarm Optimization from wandering off?

Tags: optimization, particle-swarm

I am using SAS to implement PSO, following the code given in this [link](https://www.lexjansen.com/wuss/2014/63_Final_Paper_PDF.pdf)

I also saw the pseudo code both in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization) and this [website](http://www.swarmintelligence.org/tutorials.php). In all three, I see that there are constrains on the location say -10

For example it can randomly happen that the initialized x=10 and then velocity=20, then what prevents x1 from being 30? What grantees that the solution will be within the bounded range?

I am especially concerned when I am actually seeking the solution which may be at the boundary.

Answer (score 0):

The method to bound a sprite in a game to the screen is called clipping. So after every update you would check the coordinates of the particle and keep it in check, you could either clip the coordinates or wrap it like a sphere so (x>width then x = 0).

Your problem is that you are overthinking the problem, create a prototype and the answers will flow to you.

[See my tutorial and quick code](https://techeffigytutorials.blogspot.com/2020/04/particle-swarm-optimization-explained_2.html) if you are interested.

Comment: I do  not think that hard-coded strict clipping is what OP is looking for, but your answer might provoke them to elaborate what they really want. This could be considered a comment (in contrast to an answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ), which I mention in case your post gets deleted as not being an answer or downvoted for the same reason. In that case please go on trying, I bet you can provide appreciated input elsewhere. I won't flag it now, because to me strictly you are answering the question. Good luck.